# Use Groovy To Search A File And Grab Contents Below A String

Tags: string, groovy

I'm trying to use Groovy to open a file to search for a specific substring and then grab a different substring that occurs below the first one.

For example the substring I'm searching for is "Charger is enabled. Checking charge parameters..."
and if it is found I want to get a specific string that occurs after this.

Is the best way to do this read the file into memory and search for the index of the first string?

Comment: Does the message span lines in the file? Are there lines in the file? Couldn't you use eachLine to read each line in turn and check for the first string, then switch and look for the second? (Assuming the answers to the above questions are 'no' and 'yes' respectively)

Comment: If the file is small enough, reading it into memory makes it easier to search the whole thing at once for sure. But if it's a large file, reading into memory isn't always feasible.

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, there are lines in the file and no the message doesn't span lines.  I thought of using eachLine but I couldn't determine what to do once I found the first substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
// With Java
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

def localDirectory = "";
def fileName = "";
def searchKey = "Charger is enabled. Checking charge parameters";
def searchKey2 = "";
def errorMessage = "";
FileReader fr;
BufferedReader br;

try
{  
    File f1 = new File(localDirectory+"/"+fileName);
    fr = new FileReader(f1);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    def keyFound = false;

    // Go through line by line.
    def line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        // If first string is found, process the second string.
        if(line.contains(searchKey))
        {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Do something with the second string.
                if(line.contains(searchKey2))
                {
                    keyFound=true;
                    break;
                }   
            }          
        }
        if(keyFound)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    errorMessage += "\nUnexpected Exception: " + e.getMessage();

    for (trace in e.getStackTrace())
    {
        errorMessage += "\n\t" + trace;
    }
}
finally
{
    fr?.close();
    br?.close();
}

// With Groovy
def localDirectory = "";
def fileName = "";
def searchKey = "Charger is enabled. Checking charge parameters";
def searchKey2 = "";
def errorMessage = "";

try
{  
    File f1 = new File(localDirectory+"/"+fileName);
    def keyFound = false;

    // Go through line by line.
    def line;
    f1.withReader
    {
        reader ->
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {       
                // If first string is found, process the second string.
                if(line.contains(searchKey))
                {
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // Do something with the second string.
                        if(line.contains(searchKey2))
                        {
                          keyFound=true;
                          break;
                        }                 
                    }               
                }
                if(keyFound)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
    }       
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    errorMessage += "\nUnexpected Exception: " + e.getMessage();

    for (trace in e.getStackTrace())
    {
        errorMessage += "\n\t" + trace;
    }
}
```